# Oracle SQL 12.1 removing a changing substring from a string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have the following example

```
05.04.2018 at 11:10:37 AEST
```

My goal is to remove all alpha chars from the string.
The expected result is to remove the ' at' and ' AEST' sub-strings:

**Note:** There should be only one space between the date and the time. There should be no space at the end of the string

```
05.04.2018 11:10:37
```

The 'AEST' sub-string is a timezone and can change.

This is my current SQL query:

```
select SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('05.04.2018 at 11:10:37 AEST',' at',''), ' EST| AEDT| AEST', ''),1) from dual;
```

I'm looking to enhance my query (preferably using regex) so I will not have to specify explicitly all potential values for timezone (as currently being done in the query)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `\s*[a-zA-Z]+` / `\s*[[:alpha:]]+` regex:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('05.04.2018 at 11:10:37 AEST','\s*[a-zA-Z]+','') as Result from dual
```

The pattern matches

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters (`[[:alpha:]]+` will match any letters).

See an [online Oracle demo](http://rextester.com/BTWZW51235). Output:

[image]

Comment: PERFECT. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with test as (select '05.04.2018 at 11:10:37 AEST' col from dual)
  2  select regexp_replace(col, '\s*[[:alpha:]]+') result
  3  from test;

RESULT
-------------------
05.04.2018 11:10:37

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select trim(regexp_replace(col, '[a-zA-Z]', ''))
```

I assume you want to remove the final space as well.

Comment: Thanks. That approach leaves double space between the date and time

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple! Why not without regexp? The date part and the time part are always at the same position.

```
select substr(col,1,10)  -- the date part
    ||' '||              -- the blank
    substr(col,15,8)     -- the time part
from tab;
```

e.g.

```
SQL> select substr(col,1,10)  
        ||' '||
        substr(col,15,8)  "date+time"   
     from (
        select '05.04.2018 at 11:10:37 AEST' col
            from dual) tab; 

date+time
-------------------
05.04.2018 11:10:37
```